WSO2 calls not showing on fiddler
I am using WSO2 MI 4.1.0 locally on windows and I want to capture the calls WSO2 is making towards outer services.
I normally use fiddler to capture traffic but I am not seeing the calls WSO2 makes. Do I need to configure something in my WSO2 configuration so that the traffic appears in fiddler?
I already have fiddler configured so that it decrypts https requests.

If fiddler is a Proxy server, you need to add the configs to route the traffic through the proxy. Add the following to the deployment.toml. Read more from here.
[transport.http]
sender.proxy_host= "<hostname/ip>"
sender.proxy_port= <port>

[transport.blocking.http]
sender.parameter.'http.proxyHost'= "<hostname/ip>"
sender.parameter.'http.proxyPort'= <port>

On a side note, if you just want to see the outgoing messages you can also enable wire logs.

Thank you very much, this worked like a charm. All requests appear on fiddler now.
